# Django templates: verbose version of a choice

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a model:

```
from django.db import models

CHOICES = (
    ('s', 'Glorious spam'),
    ('e', 'Fabulous eggs'),
)

class MealOrder(models.Model):
    meal = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=CHOICES)
```

I have a form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class MealOrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MealOrder
```

And I want to use formtools.preview. The default template prints the short version of the choice ('e' instead of 'Fabulous eggs'), becuase it uses

```
{% for field in form %}
<tr>
<th>{{ field.label }}:</th>
<td>{{ field.data }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}.
```

**I'd like a template as general as the mentioned, but printing 'Fabulous eggs' instead.**

*[as I had doubts where's the real question, I bolded it for all of us :)]*

I know how to get the verbose version of a choice in a way that is itself ugly:

```
{{ form.meal.field.choices.1.1 }}
```

The real pain is I need to get the selected choice, and the only way coming to my mind is iterating through choices and checking `{% ifequals currentChoice.0 choiceField.data %}`, which is even uglier.

Can it be done easily? Or it needs some template-tag programming? Shouldn't that be available in django already?

Answer (score 290):

In Django templates you can use the "[`get_FOO_display()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)" method, that will return the readable alias for the field, where 'FOO' is the name of the field.

Note: in case the standard `FormPreview` templates are not using it, then you can always [provide your own templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) for that form, which will contain something like `{{ form.get_meal_display }}`.

Comment: yes, I know. It's not as general (universal), though - unless you know a way to iterate in a template over all get_FOO_display methods of a model object :) I'm a bit too lazy for writing non-generic templates ;) 

Moreover, the docs say it's a model instance's method. Therefore it'd have to be a model form bound to an existing object which is not the case and also not general.

Comment: Note that this usage is not limited to the views, get_FOO_display() is a method on the model object itself so you can use it in model code, too!   For example, in __unicode__() it is very handy

Answer (score 68):

The best solution for your problem is to use helper functions.
If the choices are stored in the variable **CHOICES** and the model field storing the selected choice is '**choices**' then you can directly use

```
 {{ x.get_choices_display }}
```

in your template. Here, x is the model instance.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Why would you answer like this 2 years after a useful answer is already in place?  And who would vote it up?  Its the same answer as @roberto just 2 years later....

Comment: @Mark0978 the reason for upvoting this answer is because (for me) it was clearer to follow then the "top voted" answer. YMMV.

Comment: also see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4023

Answer (score 53):

My apologies if this answer is redundant with any listed above, but it appears this one hasn't been offered yet, and it seems fairly clean.  Here's how I've solved this:

```
from django.db import models

class Scoop(models.Model):
    FLAVOR_CHOICES = [
        ('c', 'Chocolate'),
        ('v', 'Vanilla'),
    ]

    flavor = models.CharField(choices=FLAVOR_CHOICES)

    def flavor_verbose(self):
        return dict(Scoop.FLAVOR_CHOCIES)[self.flavor]
```

My view passes a Scoop to the template (note: *not* Scoop.values()), and the template contains:

```
{{ scoop.flavor_verbose }}
```

Answer (score 11):

Basing on Noah's reply, here's a version immune to fields without choices:

```
#annoyances/templatetags/data_verbose.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def data_verbose(boundField):
    """
    Returns field's data or it's verbose version 
    for a field with choices defined.

    Usage::

        {% load data_verbose %}
        {{form.some_field|data_verbose}}
    """
    data = boundField.data
    field = boundField.field
    return hasattr(field, 'choices') and dict(field.choices).get(data,'') or data
```

I'm not sure wether it's ok to use a filter for such purpose. If anybody has a better solution, I'll be glad to see it :) Thank you Noah!

Comment: +1 for mentioning your path #annoyances/templatetags/... LOL ... I use get_FOO_display(), which is mentioned on the bottom of the form docs.

Comment: great idea with the use of hasattr on choices!

Answer (score 7):

We can extend the filter solution by [Noah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105638/django-templates-verbose-version-of-a-choice#answer-1105804)  to be more universal in dealing with data and field types:

```
<table>
{% for item in query %}
    <tr>
        {% for field in fields %}
            <td>{{item|human_readable:field}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Here's the code:

```
#app_name/templatetags/custom_tags.py
def human_readable(value, arg):
    if hasattr(value, 'get_' + str(arg) + '_display'):
        return getattr(value, 'get_%s_display' % arg)()
    elif hasattr(value, str(arg)):
        if callable(getattr(value, str(arg))):
            return getattr(value, arg)()
        else:
            return getattr(value, arg)
   else:
       try:
           return value[arg]
       except KeyError:
           return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
register.filter('human_readable', human_readable)
```

Comment: Seems quite universal :) Can't tell for sure, because I haven't done too much Python or Django since that time. It's pretty sad, though, that it still needs a 3rd party (not included in Django) filter (otherwise you'd tell us, Ivan, wouldn't you? ;))...

Comment: @ArturGajowy

Yes, as of today there is no such default feature in Django. I have proposed it, [who knows, maybe it will be approved](https://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/9ff2222931b381c7).

Comment: PERFECT! WORKS LIKE A CHARM! CUSTOM TEMPLATE FILTERS ROX! THANK YOU! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's any built-in way to do that. A filter might do the trick, though:

```
@register.filter(name='display')
def display_value(bf):
    """Returns the display value of a BoundField"""
    return dict(bf.field.choices).get(bf.data, '')
```

Then you can do:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ field.label }}:</th>
        <td>{{ field.data|display }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have Model.get_FOO_display() where FOO is the name of the field that has choices.

In your template do this :

```
{{ scoop.get_flavor_display }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add to your models.py one simple function:

```
def get_display(key, list):
    d = dict(list)
    if key in d:
        return d[key]
    return None
```

Now, you can get verbose value of choice fields like that:

```
class MealOrder(models.Model):
    meal = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=CHOICES)

    def meal_verbose(self):
        return get_display(self.meal, CHOICES)
```

Upd.: I'm not sure, is that solution “pythonic” and “django-way” enough or not, but it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

The extended-extended version of Noah's and Ivan's solution. Also fixed Noah's solution for Django 3.1, as `ModelChoiceIteratorValue` is now unhashable.

```
@register.filter
def display_value(value: Any, arg: str = None) -> str:
    """Returns the display value of a BoundField or other form fields"""
    if not arg:  # attempt to auto-parse
        # Returning regular field's value
        if not hasattr(value.field, 'choices'): return value.value()
        # Display select value for BoundField / Multiselect field
        # This is used to get_..._display() for a read-only form-field
        # which is not rendered as Input, but instead as text
        return list(value.field.choices)[value.value()][1]

    # usage: {{ field|display_value:<arg> }}
    if hasattr(value, 'get_' + str(arg) + '_display'):
        return getattr(value, 'get_%s_display' % arg)()
    elif hasattr(value, str(arg)):
        if callable(getattr(value, str(arg))):
            return getattr(value, arg)()
        return getattr(value, arg)

    return value.get(arg) or ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-select">
    {% for key, value in form.meal.field.choices %}
        {% if form.meal.value == key %}
            <option value="{{ form.key }}" selected>{{ value }}</option>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hey what about that way?

in models.py

```
class MealOrder(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('s', 'Glorious spam'),
        ('e', 'Fabulous eggs'),
    )
    meal = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=CHOICES)
    meal_value = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, 
        editable=False)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.meal == "s":
            self.meal_value = "Glorious spam"
        elif self.meal == "e":
            self.meal_value = "Fabulous eggs"
        super(MealOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

in views.py

```
from .models import MealOrder

def meal_order(request):
    meals = MealOrder.objects.all()

    return render(request, "meals.html", {
        "meals": meals,
    })
```

in meals.html

```
{% for meal in meals %}
    {{meal.meal_value }}
{%endfor%}
```