# How access tuple item

Tags: django-templates

*models.py*

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    GENDER = (('M',"Male"),('F',"Female"))
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = GENDER)
```

*template.html*

```
{% for item in mymodels %}
    {{ item.GENDER[item.gender] }} #HOW TODO?
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105638/django-templates-verbose-version-of-a-choice)

I think that best bet is to use helper function that returns proper value or extend/write new filter.