# Can't use get_FOO_display with forms

Tags: django

Hi I just want to display in a template the human readable text of a choice field from a form. The problem is the template does not display anything. What am I doing wrong? Code below. Thanks.

forms.py

```
class MathsForm(forms.Form):

    operation_choices = [
        (0, None),
        (1, 'Addition'),
        (2, 'Subtration'),
        (3, 'Times'),
        (4, 'Division')
    ]

    operation = forms.ChoiceField(choices=operation_choices, help_text="(required)")
```

views.py

```
def maths(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MathsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            return render(request, 'maths/test.html', {'cd': cd})
    else:
        form = MathsForm(
            initial={'operation': 1}
        )
    return render(request, 'maths/maths.html', {'form': form})
```

template - maths.html

```
{{ cd.get_operation_display }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `get_operation_display` *on a model field*
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

You appear to be trying to use it on the `cleaned_data` dict of the form

I don't think the `get_FOO_display` method exists for form fields

This SO answer details a custom template filter which will give you the 'display' value of the currently selected choice for a form field:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1108875/202168

Comment: Ok so it only works on a Django model then. Thought that was the case. I tried to implement what you linked to but no luck. The mentioned answer simply returned the 0,1,2 Django stored data and not the human readable text. Thanks.

Comment: `{{ form.operation|data_verbose }}` returned `1` ?  I think this may be a type casting issue... the choices keys are `int`s but maybe the field data is `str` ..try modifying the filter accordingly

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code and it seems to work on the form instance. It does not however work if you call the method cleaned_data on the form thou.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the cleaned data as cd, you can pass the selected operation itself in views.py:

```
def maths(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MathsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            op_dict = dict(form.fields['operation'].choices)
            op = op_dict[int(cd['operation'])]
            return render(request, 'maths/test.html', {'op': op})
    else:
        form = MathsForm(
            initial={'operation': 1}
        )
    return render(request, 'maths/maths.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Tried this and it works, but I have many more form fields. So I don't think this approach will work as all my form fields use the same key 0,1,2 etc. How can it be adapted for many more form fields? Thanks

Comment: It will work for other choice fields also. You will need to add more context variables. Just replace 'operations' in the above code for each variable or create a function to reduce the repeated code.