# Django template: force choices on field and print display value with get_FOO_display()

Tags: python, django

I want a model with 5 choices, but I cannot enforce them and display the display value in template. I am using CharField(choice=..) instead of ChoiceField or TypeChoiceField as in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display). I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105638/django-templates-verbose-version-of-a-choice) but they don't work for me (see below).

model.py:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False)
    ILR_scale = (
        (5, 'Native'),
        (4, 'Full professional proficiency'),
        (3, 'Professional working proficiency'),
        (2, 'Limited professional proficiency'),
        (1, 'Elementary professional proficiency')
        )
    level = models.CharField(help_text='Choice between 1 and 5', default=5, max_length=25, choices=ILR_scale)
    def level_verbose(self):
        return dict(Language.ILR_scale)[self.level]
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['level','id']
    def __unicode__(self):
        return ''.join([self.language, '-', self.level])
```

view.py

```
..
def index(request):
language = Language.objects.all()
..
```

mytemplate.html

```
<div class="subheading strong-underlined mb-3 my-3">
      Languages
      </div>
      {% regroup language|dictsortreversed:"level" by level as level_list %}
      <ul>
        {% for lan_list in level_list %}
        <li>
          {% for lan in lan_list.list %}
          <strong>{{ lan.language }}</strong>: {{ lan.level_verbose }}{%if not forloop.last%},{%endif%}
          {% endfor %}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

From shell:

```
python3 manage.py shell
from resume.models import Language
l1=Language.objects.create(language='English',level=4)
l1.save()
l1.get_level_display()   #This is good
Out[20]: 'Full professional proficiency'
```

As soon as I create a Language instance from shell I cannot load the site. It fails at line 0 of the template with Exception Type: KeyError, Exception Value:   '4', Exception Location: /models.py in level_verbose, line 175 (which is the return line of the level_verbose method).

Also, I was expecting a validation error here from shell:

```
l1.level='asdasd'
l1.save()     #Why can I save this instance with this level?
```

And I can also save a shown above when using ChoiceField, meaning that I do not understand what that field is used for.

How to force instances to take field values within choices, and display the display value in templates?

Comment: it is looking for a string '4' not 4 in the dict. try - try . - `return dict(Language.ILR_scale)[int(self.leve)]`

Comment: You are mixing up strings and integers. If you wantto use integer keys you should probably use an `IntegerField` instead of a `CharField`. This will ensure that values are properly cast as integers before being saved.

Comment: yes, that fixes it. and I think ChoiceField is for forms, not for models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is the common issue even when I started with django. So first let's look at django's feature that you can do it like below (Note: your choice case's value are going to be store as integer so you should use `models.IntegerField` instead of `models.CharField`):

- [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) : you are very near about this solution.

As you can see in documentation `FOO` is the field name of your model. in your case it is `level` so when you want to access corresponding choice value in shell or view you can call method with model instance as below as you have already mentioned:

```
`l1.get_level_display()`
```

but when you want to access it in template file you need to write it like below:

```
{{ l1.get_level_display }}
```

- Now let's look at your method `level_verbose()` if you see quite again your model is a class and `level_verbose()` is the method you have created you can access `self.ILR_scale` directly just as you have used `self.level`

the main catch in you create dictionary of ILR_scale it's keys are Integer values `(i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` but you have used `CharField()` to store the level values which returns you string values `(i.e. '1', '2', '3', '4' or '5')` and in python dictionary key 1 and '1' are both different one is integer and other is string. So you may change your model field to `models.IntegerField()` or you can access the keys like

```
dict(self.ILR_scal)[int(self.level)]
```

Comment: Of course! IntegerField works. I still find it strange that I can save l1.level=555, but then the site crashes. For this reason I think it would be safer to use validators. Now let me try get_FOO_display..

Comment: you are using choices to store values in model that means django is validating your result when you run your program in template; if you assign statically this way it won't properly handle any exception.

Comment: yes, {{ lan.get_level_display }} works too. It wasn't working for me because of the wrong CharField. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `models.CharField`  but you have to set field option `choices` to your tuples.

For exapmle:

```
FRESHMAN = 'FR'
SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
JUNIOR = 'JR'
SENIOR = 'SR'
LEVELS = (
    (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
    (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
    (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
    (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
)
level = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=LEVELS,
    default=FRESHMAN,
)
```

Then in your template you can use [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) for example:
`{{l1.get_level_display}}`

See more in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/)